# Consume WCF Data service in client application throws error

Tags: wcf

I am working on WCF Data service which imported stored procedure, as below.

```
    [WebGet]
    public List<GetMTSearchResultTest_Result> GettMTSearchResultTest()
    {
        MediaMarketResearch_PRODEntities ent = new MediaMarketResearch_PRODEntities();
        return ent.GetMTSearchResultTest().ToList();
    }
```

when i consuming this in my client application it says error as "The closed type MMRClient.MMRServiceReference.GetMTSearchResultTest_Result does not have a corresponding element settable property."

I am getting this error while bind to the grid view as below.

```
    DataServiceContext context = new DataServiceContext(new Uri("http://localhost:4131/MMRDataService.svc/"));
    IEnumerable<GetMTSearchResultTest_Result> empResult = context.Execute<GetMTSearchResultTest_Result>(new Uri("http://localhost:4131/MMRDataService.svc/GettMTSearchResultTest"));
    GridView1.DataSource = empResult;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Note: I imported this stored proc as complex type.

Please advice me on this.

Regards,

Jaydeep

Answer (score 0):

I think this [link](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/41682/116936.aspx#116936) may help you (see the selected answer).

Essentially, what the solution may be is to create a partial class for `GetMTSearchResultTest_Result` and decorate it with a `DataServiceKey` attribute, providing a non-nullable column that acts as a primary key (although I don't think it has to be unique).

So your partial class would look something like:

```
[DataServiceKey("YourKeyColumnName")]
public partial class GetMTSearchResultTest_Result {
}
```

If you're just doing reads, I don't think you'll need any implementation.

Hopefully this works.  Let me know if there are issues/questions and I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a new service reference to a non data service. That is to a normal WCF service. You can simply have a [ContractOperation] returning a list of the troubled "complex types" and that's it.

This way you would have two services the original data service and a new normal WCF service. But this shouldn't be such an issue. You don't have to make the troubled "complex type" as a Entity.