# EF4: The closed type 'xxxx' does not have a corresponding element settable property

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

I'm using [this guide](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/5959/) to call stored procedure in my projet which using EF4 EDMX through WCFDataservice.

I have mapped a complex type to return items from the stored procedure. If I call the method by http, the XML'result is perfect, but when I call with this code:

```
public void Test()
{
    Uri methodUri = new Uri(entities.BaseUri + "/GetCase");
    List<CaseFiltered> result = entities.Execute<CaseFiltered>(methodUri).ToList();
}
```

I get this exception **The closed type CaseFiltered does not have a corresponding element settable property.**

I had try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658544/consume-wcf-data-service-in-client-application-throws-error) but it doesn't work for me.

Have you a solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Post your solution as an answer please and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I find the solution according this [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataservices/thread/416f1e2f-aa57-4749-8b05-bd7f1c92cc2c)

> Actually, you did everything
>   right...However, our client library
>   does not support materialization of a
>   collection of complex types directly
>   (yet). If you look at the output of
>   the service op, you would see a list
>   of  tag, rather than an Atom
>   Feed.

My workaround: I'm using Case **entities**, not the CaseFiltered **complex type**